# UIPageViewController - added subview causes a bug in the first controller's view - other controllers are fine

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

- So I have a **UIPageViewController**. It houses **5 UIHostingViewControllers (Swift UI)**
- I add the hosting view controller as a **child** then setup views as per recommended approach
- **Everything works** and I am **able to swipe** between controllers
- Now I need to **show highlighted circles** to give users an idea of which page they are viewing as they scroll. This is where the problem occurs
- I add these circles as a **subview** on the **UIPageViewController's view**. Everything works fine but the **first controller** of the page view controller alone has a **bug with the view**. The view's frame does not fill the page view's bounds
- This is what I get. As you can see in the below image, all other controllers are able to fit the view except the first one. This behaviour only happens when I try to add those indicator circles as a subview of **self.view or UIPageViewController.view**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class TutorialController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{
    var controllers = [UIViewController]()
    var circleStackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.axis = .horizontal
        sv.spacing = 16
        return sv
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        dataSource = self
        setupViewControllers()
    }
    
    fileprivate func setupViewControllers(){
        let tutorialPage1 = UIHostingController(rootView: TutorialPage1())
        let sampleViewController1 = UIViewController()
        sampleViewController1.addChild(tutorialPage1)
        tutorialPage1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sampleViewController1.view.addSubview(tutorialPage1.view)
        tutorialPage1.didMove(toParent: sampleViewController1)
        tutorialPage1.view.frame = sampleViewController1.view.bounds
        controllers.append(sampleViewController1)
        
        let tutorialPage2 = UIHostingController(rootView: TutorialPage2())
        let sampleViewController2 = UIViewController()
        sampleViewController2.addChild(tutorialPage2)
        tutorialPage2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sampleViewController2.view.addSubview(tutorialPage2.view)
        tutorialPage2.didMove(toParent: sampleViewController2)
        tutorialPage2.view.frame = sampleViewController2.view.bounds
        controllers.append(sampleViewController2)
                       
        setViewControllers([controllers.first!], direction: .forward, animated: false)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        controllers.forEach { (_) in
            let circleView = UIView()
            circleView.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, size: .init(width: 24, height: 24))
            circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
            circleView.clipsToBounds = true
            circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
            self.circleStackView.addArrangedSubview(circleView)
            self.circleStackView.bringSubviewToFront(view)
        }

        view.addSubview(circleStackView)
        circleStackView.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 16, right: 0))
        circleStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = controllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == viewController}) ?? 0
        if index == 0{
            return nil
        }
        return controllers[index - 1]
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let index = controllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == viewController}) ?? 0
        if index == controllers.count - 1{
            return nil
        }
        return controllers[index + 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be possible to share the code of TutorialPage1 and TutorialPage2?

Comment: @IFTTT It is a basic VStack with a Rectangle() & a Spacer(). Like I said the views are rendered accurately as long as I don't add any subview to the page view controller. The moment I add those circles as subviews, the first view controller alone gets displaced like in the image

Comment: The problem seems to be specific to using UIStackView along with SwiftUI. I tried replacing the stackview with a uilabel and the issue didn't show up.

Comment: @IFTTT Oh that's weird. Is this a known issue? If so you can post it as an answer, I'll mark it as the right answer. I think a good workaround would be to house the page view controller into another view controller with a bottom padding and add a stack view there. Then probably use delegate to detect page swipes & change the alpha value of those circles.

Answer (score 0):

I would try moving your call to `setupViewControllers()` from `viewDidLoad()` to  `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` before you set up your circleView controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the input and nope that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing
tutorialPage1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tutorialPage2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

The reason might be that ios is expecting at least one of the auto-resizing or the auto-layout.
The frame-based layout seems to have some issues with swift UI.